# Netbeans 8.0.1 not opening on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, netbeans, macos-mojave

After upgrade to Mojave, Netbeans 8.0.1 is not opening anymore ; it shows the splash screen, but closes right after.

It probably has to be with a JDK update; which JDK version it supports and how can i downgrade the JDK

Thanks !

Comment: Edit file **netbeans.conf** in the **etc** directory within your NetBeans installation. The value of the property **netbeans_jdkhome** should point to a valid JDK installation directory that you want to use as the default in NetBeans. If you see the splash screen followed by NetBeans closing you probably have an invalid value (or no value) for **netbeans_jdkhome**. If that is not the problem then look for relevant error messages in the NetBeans log file named **messages.log** within directory **/var/log**.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you but how can i know where this netbeans.conf  file is located ?

Comment: The exact location may vary from release to release of NetBeans, and depend on exactly how you chose to install NetBeans, but somewhere under your NetBeans installation directory locate a directory named **etc**. The file **netbeans.conf** is in that directory. It is just a text file containing properties. The entry for property **netbeans_jdkhome** may or may not be commented, but if it is not then it must specify a valid path to your JDK.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem ! Please put as answer and i'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans reads a configuration file named **netbeans.conf** on startup. It is just a text file containing properties, located in its **etc** directory within the NetBeans installation. One of the properties it might specify is the path to the default JDK to be used via property **netbeans_jdkhome**.

If that path becomes invalid (e.g. possibly due to upgrading on Mac) then NetBeans won't start; as described in the OP it will display the splash screen then close down.

The solution is simply to edit property **netbeans_jdkhome** to specify a valid path to the JDK that you want to use.

Note that **netbeans_jdkhome** is not necessarily specified at all in **netbeans.conf**, since NetBeans has other ways of determining the default JDK path. But if **netbeans_jdkhome** is specified it is crucial that the path is valid.