# How to configure Apache NetBeans with JDK 12 (sdkman) on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, macos-mojave, sdkman

I'm trying to install NetBeans on macOS Mojave - I want to work with the Matisse GUI builder.

I installed Open JDK 12 via [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/). Then I ran [this installation script](https://github.com/carljmosca/netbeans-macos-bundle), which the Apache NetBeans docs refer to.

However, after installation NetBeans didn't start. I downgraded to Open JDK 11 via SDKMan, but it also didn't work.

Any ideas how to debug the problem? Anyone used NetBeans with a recent JDK version (10+) on MacOS?

Comment: Check this https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html

Comment: Re _"Any ideas how to debug the problem?"_, you need to provide more information to resolve this. Update your post with: [1] Relevant information from the NetBeans log file **messages.log**. See [here for details](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile) on how to locate it. [2] The entire content of **netbeans.conf**. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967489/2985643) for how to locate that file on MacOS. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632296/2985643) describes one possible cause of your problem.